# asp.net application moved - namespace not found

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I had an installation of Umbraco in a subdirectory of wwwroot.
Everything worked well.
Now I moved all the files and folders of the Umbraco installation from the subdirectory to the wwwroot.
When I try to load the backend I get an error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'UmbracoMembership' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Now `UmbracoMembership` is a class of a custom usercontrol, which resides in the `Membership.dll` file which is in the bin folder.

Before the move everything worked. I'm guessing this has something to do with where asp.net is looking for the assemblies (and not an Umbraco specific issue), but I have no idea where and how to fix this.

Thank you!
-Elad

Answer (score 1):

Check if you need to append namespace definition in your web.config. These will be applied to all pages.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I didn't add it to begin with and everything worked. It stopped working once I moved it to the new directory.